# Does / will Slack posts appear in a case feed like chatter posts do?

Tags: casefeed, slack

The good thing (for us) about chatter, is that chat posts appear as a feed item with a time stamp in the case feed.
For many reasons we would like to migrate from chatter to Slack.
BUT
Will a slack post in a thread that is related to a case, appear in the case feed just like chatter posts do now?

And if not now, does anyone know if this is on the development calendar of Salesforce/Slack?